# Clone element not working jquery

Tags: jquery, clone

HTML

```
<h2>Click Here</h2>
<div class="holder">
  <a href="#">One</a>
  <a href="#">Two</a>
  <a href="#">Three</a>
</div>
```

Im triying to clone the anchors one at a time after the last one.The final result should be something like one two three one two three etc.My idea is to have a var equal to the first index 0 which is the first anchor. And after the loop if that var gets to index 3 to turn back to 0

```
var click = $(".holder a")[0];
var length = $(".holder a").length;

$("h2").click(function () {
    for (var click; click < length; click++) {
        if (click == $(".holder a")[3]) {
            click = $(".holder a")[0];
            $(click).insertAfter(".holder a:last");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am a little confused are you trying to copy all of the elements right after the original list

Comment: I'm assuming you mean $("h2").click and not $("h3").click?

Comment: Your "var length=" statement is missing the jQuery $ selector.

Comment: Are you trying to add a new anchor after the last anchor? It is a little unclear what you are trying to have happen when you click.

Comment: this is total mess `for (var click; click < length; click++) {`

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the effect your are trying to achieve.

```
var $holder = $('.holder');

$('h3').on("click", function(){

    $holder.find('a').each(function(){
        $holder.append($(this).clone());
    });

});
```